# Node.js | "events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event" after publishing to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I made web app using NodeJS.
When I'm running it on localhost:8000 everything works well, but after deploying it to heroku Im getting the following tail log:
[image]

I have followed the DOCS and already done these:

1. and getting the port from ENV dynamically.
2. I have made a Procfile with "web: node app.js" in it.
3. added to   "engines": {
   "node": "10.16.3"
   },

I tried to look after event.js line 174 problem online but couldn't find any solution. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by removing everything except /node_modules from my .gitignore file (had there .env and some more lines)